# Edit rejected when it fixes a problem with an answer?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I've edited three answers on a single post with one being rejected because of the following.

> This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.

There were already comments pointing out the issue so I fixed it in the answer. I don't see how there's any difference in me editing the answer and fixing the issue vs me commenting like others and then the original person changing the answer.

As you can see the answers were accepted by the people that originally wrote them yet rejected by people reviewing them. Is it not right to fix an issue myself instead of leaving it for the original owner to fix?

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16203643
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16203638
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16203641

Edit: The edits I've added are the same types I've been doing since I created my account 4 years ago so either I've been doing something wrong for the last 4 years or the rejection was wrong.

Comment: If the code is correct (and it does not depend on version ecc), it should not have been declined (I skip code edit's where I'm not sure). However you risk a lot doing these edits (high risk that people do not skip, but push reject). **Solution 1**: Post comment under answer or an own improved answer. **Solution 2** Post a really good edit summary why your code is correct and the old one is not, link to documentation ecc. **Solution 3** Get some rep and no more review queue

Comment: 1. All the answers had the same issue which had already been discussed and that's why I edited them. 2. The comments on the post as well as answers basically cover that. 3. I'm trying but things like this don't really help with that. 

Comment: If it already have been discussed some where add a link to that discussion in edit summary. If people are not skipping do what you can to avoid that they push reject, scare them away.

Comment: 1. Seeing one person edit all answers on a post actually looks more sketchy (in my opinion). 2. We can't see comments in the review queue. You can't assume that a reviewer is going to open the actual post in a new tab.